# How do I install office 2010 with the Serial Key embedded?

Tags: windows, microsoft-office, microsoft-office-2010

I am looking to upgrade roughly 150 clients from office 2007 to office 2010.  As we have a corporate serial key I'm not really want to install this by entering in the key manually by myself every time.  I know that you can somehow "embed" the serial key into the installation files so that you do not need to manually enter the serial key, but do now know how.  So how do I go about this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out this [walk-through](http://ye110wbeard.wordpress.com/2010/06/21/automated-install-of-office-2010/)  It requires an XML file similar to Windows 7 unattended install.

Alternatively, you could make all the end users fend for themselves during the upgrade :)

Comment: This was what I ended up doing as this was a quick fix.

Answer (score 4):

Considering the amount of users, if you have a Volume License key you can set up a KMS server and have the activation automated locally rather then having to enter the key. You can read more about KMS (Volume Activation) [here](http://www.microsoft.com/licensing/existing-customers/product-activation.aspx)

The idea is that you have your own activation server locally on your network, which will automatically be detected when Office and Windows for that matter, tries to activate. It will use the KMS key provided by Microsoft to activate. The advantage is that the end users do not need a key at all, and during activation it will retrieve the correct key from the server.

We use it on our network with huge success.

Comment: +1 for KMS.  With that many users, this will save a lot of time.

Answer (score 0):

Options:

1. Run setup /admin and you get a nice little gui which allows you to enter a product key and save the results as a msp file. Put this msp file in the updates directory
2. Edit the config.xml file. This file will be under the release directory (ProPlus.ww or Enteprise.ww or something like that). Be aware: this leaves your key in plain text on your distribution point
3. Use the Volume Activation Management Tool after installation
4. Setup your own Key Management Server